# When my fprintf receives user input it crashes

Tags: c, file, printf, scanf

This is a basic address book program that a user can add and delete people from and I am trying to eventually take the data saved in the array and store it in a text file.


In the `choose` function when `ichoice == 8` the program is supposed to print the integer itter to the text file list.txt. It will print 0 when the program first opens and I haven't done anything to change it, but when I add names to the address book causing itter to increase the program crashes whenever I go back and try to save to list.txt.

```
        else if (ichoice == 8) {
            FILE *outFile = fopen("list.txt", "w");
            if (outFile != NULL) {
                printf("%d", itter);
                fprintf(outFile, "%d", itter);
            }
            fclose(outFile);
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230314/discussion-on-question-by-devin-bowen-when-my-fprintf-receives-user-input-it-cra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in the code fragment:

- you `fclose(outFile)` even if the `fopen` call was unsuccessful.
- you do not append a newline after the number, causing further output to be indistinguishable from the conversion of `itter`.
- `fopen("list.txt", "w");` will truncate the file if it already exists: this might not be the expected behavior.

Here is a modified snippet:

```
        else if (ichoice == 8) {
            FILE *outFile = fopen("list.txt", "w"); // or possibly "a"
            if (outFile != NULL) {
                printf("%d\n", itter);
                fprintf(outFile, "%d\n", itter);
                fclose(outFile);
            }
        }
```